# Can Enunciate take Java Interface as data types?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, enunciate

I want to use Enunciate to automatically generate documentation of my REST API.

The JAX-RS annotated code goes something like this:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public IAuthentication login(CLogin aLogin) throws XException {
    return this.pManager.authenticate(aLogin);
}
```

`IAuthentication` is an interface, and it has to remain one. This is because I use injection, and I cannot predict the exact type returned by the method `authenticate()`. `CLogin` however is a class, and it is OK since it is a specialisation of the type that method `authenticate()` accepts.

Now my problem is that only Request Body is document in the Enunciate-generated documentation, and not the Response Body. Enunciate seems to ignore Java interfaces when looking for potential data types, with the following message:

> [DEBUG] [ENUNCIATE] com.example.IAuthentication isn't a potential Jackson type because it's not a class or an enum.

My interfaces are annotated with JAXB annotations. They are accessible form the source path.

```
@XmlRootElement
public interface IAuthentication {
    /* methods signatures */
}
```

Is there a way to tell Enunciate that Java interfaces are OK as data types and must be taken into account.

**Addendum**

A real-life example of the JSON output of this method:

```
{
    "token": "imec51lpb72lgsdrb0ftvfomt3",
    "auth_key": ""
}
```

Comment: Can you try annotating the classes which implements the interface with the Jaxb annotations ?

Comment: I did. A class `@XmlRootElement
public class CAuthentication implements IAuthentication` is already there. It shows in the Data Type list. However, the Response Body of method POST is still not documented.

Comment: Which implementation of jaxb are you using , maybe Jackson ?

Comment: Indeed. I use Jackson 2.5.

Comment: Can you post the output of the service, i mean what is generating jackson, i found a validation in previus versions but i couldn't find it in 2,5. That output and example of your class CAuthentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @stoicflame answer to [this issue](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/issues/551), version 2.7 of Enunciate doesn't seem to support Java interfaces as data types.

I resorted to using the JavaDoc tag `@returnWrapped`. Another option would be the Enunciate-specific annotation `@TypeHint`. The JavaDoc tag spares me external runtime dependencies though.

**Edit:**
Version 2.9.0 of Enunciate now [supports documenting interface types](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/releases/tag/v2.9.0).